# Automating Pivot Table invalid argument

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, pivot-table, office-scripts

When attempting to automate my pivot tables from a dataset using Office Scripts, the script keeps saying there is an invalid argument in the " let pivotTable = newSheet.addPivotTable("mypivot", table, "A1");"

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
// Create a PivotTable based on a table in the current worksheet.
let sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
let table = sheet.getTables()[0];

// Add the PivotTable to a new worksheet.
let newSheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Holtersum");
let pivotTable = newSheet.addPivotTable("mypivot", table, "A1");

// Add fields to the PivotTable to show "Sales" per "Type".
pivotTable.addRowHierarchy(pivotTable.getHierarchy("Operator Name"));
pivotTable.addDataHierarchy(pivotTable.getHierarchy("Holter"));
```

}

I expected a pivot table to be created with values from two columns

Comment: Are you sure your code is VBA?

Comment: Don't use a Function. Create a Sub by recording a Macro, click through the steps you want to perform, and you'll have all the code you need. Try that and feed back here with your results.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue comes from the fact that you reference A1 in your PivotTable variable. If you add the sheet name to this section it should work. So you would update from this:

```js
let pivotTable = newSheet.addPivotTable("mypivot", table, "A1");
```

to this:

```js
let pivotTable = newSheet.addPivotTable("mypivot", table, "Holtersum!A1");
```